# PHP Excel from array merge cells

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

I export a table of participants. I have a form for the participants, where I have dynamically generated section for choosing meals. It comes from array like this:

```
$days = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Saturday',
        'meals' => array(
            array(
                'title' => 'Brf',
                'price' => 25
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Lnch',
                'price' => 60
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'Dnr',
                'price' => 35
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I need to merge and center day titles (Thursday, Friday...) and merge with number of cells on the right. The number of merged cells equals to `count($days[$day]['meals'])`.

The goal looks like this:
[image: The goal of all this]

I use creating table from array `$PHPexcelsheet->from_array($a);` for table data. If it could be used for the header too, would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to the solution. Doesn't seem so pretty, as I supposed, and also doesn*t work with more than 26 cols (which I don't need), but works.

```
$i = 0;
$c = 4;
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
while ($i < count($ceny_jidlo)) {
    $den = $ceny_jidlo[$i];

    $s = $alphabet[$c];

    $sheet->setCellValue("{$s}1", $den['short']);

    $co = $c;
    $c = $c + count($den['opts']) - 1;
    $e = $alphabet[$c];

    for ($j = $co; $j <= $c; $j++)
        colstyle($shit, $alphabet[$j], $eRow, 10);

    $sheet->mergeCells("{$s}1:{$e}1");

    $c++;
    $i++;
}
```